# Making Bitmap from BufferedGraphics C#

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I was making a simple program in **C# WinForms**, something like MSPaint. The one thing where I'm currently stuck is that I want to make **Bitmap** from the **BufferedGraphics** on which I'm drawing and then save it. But when I save it, there is nothing in the file, its just a blank image.

**Here is the code:**

```
private BufferedGraphics picture;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        picture = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current.Allocate(MainPanel.CreateGraphics(), MainPanel.DisplayRectangle);
        picture.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, MainPanel.DisplayRectangle);
        picture.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        picture.Graphics.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    }

    private void Draw()
    {
        if (mouseDown)
        {
            Point cursorPos = MainPanel.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            picture.Graphics.FillEllipse(selectedColor, cursorPos.X - slider.Value / 2, cursorPos.Y - slider.Value / 2, slider.Value, slider.Value);
            picture.Render();
        }
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(MainPanel.Width, MainPanel.Height, picture.Graphics);

        result.Save("image.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    }
```

Comment: ok what documentation says about 3rd parameter (Graphics) of Bitmap constructor... I dont's see *copy graphics to bitmap* ... because it can't Graphics object doesn't contain any drawings - you can draw on it but you can't get drawings from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code snippet;

```
BufferedGraphics buffer;
int bufferWidth, bufferHeight;

using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bufferWidth, bufferHeight))
{
  using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
  {
    buffer.Render(graphics);
  }

  bitmap.Save("a.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Comment: **Thanks**,I should have looked for all the parameters for the `BufferderGraphics.Render()` method. I thought that it was just for refreshing. xD